# Insert record with Subsonic 3.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, subsonic

I have an issue with subsonic. I'm trying to insert a record into table with primary key set to identity with autoincrement. I've got an exception:

```
Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Zaposleni' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.
```

How do I do this? Please, can anybody provide me an example?

I should mention that I'm using ASP.NET MVC, and SubSonic entities for view model binding.

Answer (score 1):

> > when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

That's your issue. If you've set your identity in your DB, be sure to regenerate - this makes the PK un-writable.